# GIT - Checking-out project subdirectory

Tags: git

On a local drive, the project files are in directory `bar`. However in git repository, theys are in the `foo` sub-directory of `https://:@git.<domain>/kerberos/my_repo` (i.e. in `my_repo/foo`)

I get an **error**, when I do

`git clone https://:@git.<domain>/kerberos/my_repo/foo bar`

But it is **ok** doing the following

`git clone https://:@git.<domain>/kerberos/my_repo bar`

Although then the folder structure is `bar/my_repo/foo`. This is NOT what I need.
I want files from `foo` to be placed right in the `bar` directory.

Is there any good solution to that?

Answer (score 1):

Basically no. Unlike svn, a git repo can only be checked out in its entirety.

Comment: Is the only way to delete and create new repository that has a proper folder name?

Comment: Could you perhaps create a symlink on your local copy, which you don't check in to the repository?

Answer (score 0):

Git handles version controlling with just one file, that's called ***.git***.

So it seems like the ***.git*** of your remote is right under the `my_repo` folder.

Therefore you can clone `my_repo` but not specifically `my_repo/foo`.

As you may realize, as SVN has its 'signature' on each subfolders of root too, checking-out `my_repo/foo` would be possible via SVN.